# ngx-translate translate also the given parameter

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate and its instant method. My translation key is composed by some text and two placeholders/parameters:

```
"invoice": "New {{code}} ({{rechnungsNr}})"
```

While `{{rechnungsNr}}` is a number, the parameter `{{code}}` is a string (I would pass another translation key) and needs also to be translated. However it is translated as plain text.

Here how I invoke it:

```
this.translationService.instant(
  'invoice',
  {
    code: invoices.fsl_herkunft,   //I need this to have be translated as well
    rechnungsNr: notificationItem.rechnungsNummer
  }
);
```

Is it possible to translate also parameters without having to invoke the `instant()` method to translate the parameter first and pass it as parameter to the second `instant()`?